# How to use Objectify in angularJS javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-app-engine, objectify

I am new to angularjs programming. I am trying to insert data to Google Cloud endpoints javascript but we can do in java by creating new class and add objectify. 
How to use class object in javascript and annote it using objectify @Id to the String. 
As i am getting "com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving com.example.mohanvaradarajan.app: Cannot save an entity with a null String @Id: com.example.mohanvaradarajan.app" error in response

```
$scope.callgapi = function () {
                   $scope.gresult = "Inserting data...";

                   GApi.execute('myApi', 'insert',datanew).then(function (resp) {
                       $scope.gresult = resp.result.data;
                   }, function (resp) {
                       console.log('Error: (' + resp);
                       $scope.gresult="An error has occurred.";
                   });
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is server-side. You have an entity with a `String` id and you aren't initializing it. If you want an autogenerated id, use `Long` as the id type.

Comment: how can i add member type in javascript. the datanew is the javascript object as below
     var datanew = {};
                   
                   datanew.Id = "name";
                   datanew.start= "1000";
                   datanew.end = 1100;
                   datanew.total= 100;